# Azure offering two different prices for same service in two different accounts

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Im about to get a test server at Azure (B2ms) that we will utilize for a short period of time. By mistake, I logged into the wrong Azure account, and I got this quote (East US):

[image]

That's for East US, Windows 2022 datacenter Edition.

Then I logged into the right account to start over with the purchase but I got a totally different quote, with a pretty different pricing structure, with even less options. East US, same availability options, same zone, same security type. I just changed the account:

[image]

The most difficult part for me to get is that, at the account I spend the less money per month (Only 230 bucks), I get a better price that my production account, where I spend $2K a month.

Im going for the cheaper one, but Im trying to understand why this is happening. BTW, it only happens with Windows Virtual Machine (not with Linux).

Thanks.

Comment: Are the subscription types similar?

Comment: Yes, the same, "Azure Plan". Just the compute quotas are different (that's why at the 2nd image there are less available options)

Comment: Different subscriptions (Pay-as-you-go, Test/MSDN, Enterprise, etc) can get different prices. Prices also vary per data center.

Comment: Hi CSharpRocks. Thanks. I understand, but the subscription is of the same type at both accounts. I dont know about the data center. I selected "East US" on both accounts. Anyway, I got the VM at the cheaper account, but its not the account where I wanted to get it. Thanks.